# What is called the progression by using multiplication?

Tags: sequences-and-series

given 2 integers ex. `x = 1000` and `y = 1`, where `x` is constant and `y` increments by 1.

In each iteration we multiply `x` by `y + 1`, that is:

1. step 1 = x * y
2. step 2 = x * (y + 1)
3. step 3 = x * (y + 2)
4. // etc...
5. step z = x * (y + n)

Is there some name that could be given to this progression type?
ex. I know there exist exponential, geometric, arithmetic progressions, but how do you call this one?

Comment: Did you mean to use the same $x$ at each step, or for consecutive terms to have ratio $y+n$? Because you seem surprised to have been told what you've presented is arithmetic.

Comment: yes same `x` only factor increments by 1 each time, formula on wikipedia made me think that there must be substraction involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you subtract any two consecutive terms you will always get the value $x$. This means that your sequence is an **arithmetic progression**.

Comment: clever way to define arithmetic progression!

Comment: I've seen it used sometimes as a test for an arithmetic progression, or sometimes as a definition. Either way, it's equivalent to to the $a_n=a_1+(n-1)d$ definition.

Comment: You could also notice that if you think about it, "common difference" is just another way of saying "if you subtract any two consecutive terms you will always get the same value".

Answer (score 1):

It is an A.P with common difference of 1000

Comment: are you saying this is arithmetic progression?

Comment: Is it x power or x into

Comment: not power, it's `x` multiplied by `y + 1`

Comment: Then it is A.P only na

Comment: Ah ok, it looks like I didn't understand wikipedia good enough then, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A comment reveals the source of confusion. Wikipedia defines an AP by $a_n=a_1+(n-1)d$. If we write the value at step $n$ as $a_n$ we have $a_n=x(y+n-1)=a_1+d(n-1)$ with $a_1=xy,\,d=x$.